# hasAttribute -VS- getAttribute

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, img, атрибуты, properties

Тут есть решённая задача - http://plnkr.co/edit/FaKoF0M4QQB1OSdtpClb?p=preview

Суть в том, чтобы сделать предзагрузку картинок по мере прокрутки страницы.

Функцию showVisible - сделал слегка по-своему:

```
function showVisible() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {


    if (isVisible(imgs[i]) && imgs[i].hasAttribute("realsrc")) {   // <--
      imgs[i].src = imgs[i].getAttribute("realsrc");
      imgs[i].setAttribute("realsrc", "");
    }

  }
}
```

Проблема возникает в проверке:

```
 if (isVisible(imgs[i]) && imgs[i].hasAttribute("realsrc"))
```

а именно в методе **has**Attribute -
из-за него крашатся все картинки оказавшиеся в поле видимости.
Проблему решает замена **has**Attribute на **get**Attribute. Так и хочется сказать ё**ный кот, да как так то? Кто-то может объяснить почему возникает подобная дичь?

Comment: нет, при краше картинок - в консоли всё чисто

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `hasAttribute` в вашем случае вернет всегда значение `true`, вне зависимости от того, что у вас в аттрибуте, ведь согласно коду, аттрибут есть всегда, а вот значение не всегда у него есть.

А метод `getAttribute` в одном случае вернет вам адрес ссылки, а в другом случае вернет пустое значение. Что в нашем случае означает:

```
var tmp = imgs[i].getAttribute("realsrc"); // вернуло 'https://js.cx/lazyimg/3-2.jpg'
```

Значит при проверке `!tmp` - это `false`.

В противоположном случае у нас будет пустое значение, не `undefined` а просто ничего. Аттрибут есть, а значения нет.

```
var tmp = imgs[i].getAttribute("realsrc"); // вернуло '' - ничего нет
```

Значит при проверке `!tmp` - это `true`.

Поэтому вот так и получается, что условие всегда `true` - отсюда и беда.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. Да, после того как очищаем realsrc - новая пробежка по циклу берёт оттуда значение, а там пустота.